# Dropdown cannot appear in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement country and state dropdown. In my script, i included the javascript code and html form also.
This code taken from [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/)

In this jsfiddle,everything is fine. But my script isn't work properly. It doesn't show country and state dynamically.

```js
    
// Countries
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Ashmore and Cartier Island", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Clipperton Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic of the", "Congo, Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czeck Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Europa Island", "Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern and Antarctic Lands", "Gabon", "Gambia, The", "Gaza Strip", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Glorioso Islands", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Howland Island", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Ireland, Northern", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Jan Mayen", "Japan", "Jarvis Island", "Jersey", "Johnston Atoll", "Jordan", "Juan de Nova Island", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Man, Isle of", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Midway Islands", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcaim Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romainia", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Helena", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Scotland", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Spratly Islands", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Tobago", "Toga", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "USA", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands", "Wales", "Wallis and Futuna", "West Bank", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe");

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = "Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2] = "Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
s_a[3] = "Adrar|Ain Defla|Ain Temouchent|Alger|Annaba|Batna|Bechar|Bejaia|Biskra|Blida|Bordj Bou Arreridj|Bouira|Boumerdes|Chlef|Constantine|Djelfa|El Bayadh|El Oued|El Tarf|Ghardaia|Guelma|Illizi|Jijel|Khenchela|Laghouat|M'Sila|Mascara|Medea|Mila|Mostaganem|Naama|Oran|Ouargla|Oum el Bouaghi|Relizane|Saida|Setif|Sidi Bel Abbes|Skikda|Souk Ahras|Tamanghasset|Tebessa|Tiaret|Tindouf|Tipaza|Tissemsilt|Tizi Ouzou|Tlemcen";
/**s_a[4] ....
....
....
....**/
s_a[252] = "Bulawayo|Harare|ManicalandMashonaland Central|Mashonaland East|Mashonaland West|Masvingo|Matabeleland North|Matabeleland South|Midlands";


function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if (stateElementId) {
        countryElement.onchange = function () {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }
}


populateCountries("country", "state");
populateCountries("country2");
```

```html
<div>
    Country: <select id="country" name="country"></select>
    State: <select name="state" id="state"></select>  
 </div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle/code-snippet of your code?

Comment: is there an error on the console?

Comment: @zeropublix http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/

Comment: `In this jsfiddle,everything is fine. But my script isn't work properly.` Isn't working where? On your site? If so then there are other problems you haven't shown

Comment: @imanshu15 index.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: populateCountries is not defined
    at index.html:19

Comment: try to call the functions after the script

Comment: @ManojA Information related to the question should be put in the question, not comment.

Comment: move the first block of script to last part of the page

Comment: Also we have stack-snippet, so for Javascript question it's better to use that (than external link like JSFiddle).

Comment: @ManojA So that means the functions are not yet defined, so try and call the functions on $(document).ready(function () {}

Comment: Its working @AswinRamesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work by calling the functions on the bottom of the page, check this

*NB: It only works for first 4 countries(since only states for first 4 countries are only initialized in this sample)*

```js
    // Countries
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Ashmore and Cartier Island", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Clipperton Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic of the", "Congo, Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czeck Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Europa Island", "Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern and Antarctic Lands", "Gabon", "Gambia, The", "Gaza Strip", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Glorioso Islands", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Howland Island", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Ireland, Northern", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Jan Mayen", "Japan", "Jarvis Island", "Jersey", "Johnston Atoll", "Jordan", "Juan de Nova Island", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Man, Isle of", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Midway Islands", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcaim Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romainia", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Helena", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Scotland", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Spratly Islands", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Tobago", "Toga", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "USA", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands", "Wales", "Wallis and Futuna", "West Bank", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe");

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = "Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2] = "Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
s_a[3] = "Adrar|Ain Defla|Ain Temouchent|Alger|Annaba|Batna|Bechar|Bejaia|Biskra|Blida|Bordj Bou Arreridj|Bouira|Boumerdes|Chlef|Constantine|Djelfa|El Bayadh|El Oued|El Tarf|Ghardaia|Guelma|Illizi|Jijel|Khenchela|Laghouat|M'Sila|Mascara|Medea|Mila|Mostaganem|Naama|Oran|Ouargla|Oum el Bouaghi|Relizane|Saida|Setif|Sidi Bel Abbes|Skikda|Souk Ahras|Tamanghasset|Tebessa|Tiaret|Tindouf|Tipaza|Tissemsilt|Tizi Ouzou|Tlemcen";

s_a[252] = "Bulawayo|Harare|ManicalandMashonaland Central|Mashonaland East|Mashonaland West|Masvingo|Matabeleland North|Matabeleland South|Midlands";


function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if (stateElementId) {
        countryElement.onchange = function () {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }
}


    populateCountries("country", "state");
    //populateCountries("country2");
```

```html
<div>
    Country:
    <select id="country" name="country"></select>
    State:
    <select name="state" id="state"></select>          
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Script ,

```
 <script language="javascript">
    populateCountries("country", "state");
    populateCountries("country2");
 </script>
```

This portion should be move the first block of script to last part of the page, Thats why its working properly.